# emf to jpg conversion

Tags: java, video-processing

My objective is to convert emf,wmf file formats to other image file formats.

I included image4java jar and tried to convert my emf file to other formats like jpg,png.. using the following code:

```
import org.im4java.core.ConvertCmd;
import org.im4java.core.IMOperation;
import java.io.File;
public class im4java {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        File input=new File("src/image.emf");
        File output=new File("src/output.jpg");
        convertemf2png(input,output);
    }
    public static void convertemf2png(File input,File output)
    {
        try{
        IMOperation img=new IMOperation();
        img.addImage();
        img.addImage();
        ConvertCmd convert=new ConvertCmd();
        convert.run(img,new Object[]{input,output});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

while i execute it, i got the error like

1. when i use simply `convert.run(img,new Object[]{input,output});` i got

   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.File is an unsupported image-type`

   ```
           at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.resolveImages(ImageCommand.java:289)
           at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.prepareArguments(ImageCommand.java:189)
           at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:208)
           at im4java.convertemf2png(im4java.java:27)
           at im4java.main(im4java.java:18)
   ```

when i use,  `convert.run(img,new Object[]{input.getAbsolutePath(),output.getAbsolutePath()});
i got,

```
 org.im4java.core.CommandException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: Invalid Parameter - C:\vignesh\im4java\src\output.jpg
        at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:215)
        at im4java.convertemf2png(im4java.java:27)
        at im4java.main(im4java.java:18)
Caused by: org.im4java.core.CommandException: Invalid Parameter - C:\vignesh\im4java\src\output.jpg
        at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.finished(ImageCommand.java:247)
        at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.run(ProcessStarter.java:314)
        at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:211)
```

anyone please help me in fizing this issue or any other way to convert emf formatt image to other formats..Thanks in advance.

Comment: configuring environment-variable `IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH` (just `PATH` is not enough) helped me in similar situation

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the path to the ImageMagic executable - you are inadvertently calling [a windows program named convert](http://savage.net.au/ImageMagick/html/install-convert.html)

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add these lines before using the im4java commands:

```
String myPath="PATH\TO\ImageMagick";
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(myPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your images in Strings.
Make sure you set the environment variable IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH to your imagemagick path.

```
import org.im4java.core.ConvertCmd;
import org.im4java.core.IMOperation;

public class im4java {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        String input = "src/image.emf";
        String output = "src/output.jpg";
        convertemf2png(input,output);
    }
    public static void convertemf2png(String input,String output)
    {
        try{
        IMOperation img=new IMOperation();
        img.addImage();
        img.addImage();
        ConvertCmd convert=new ConvertCmd();
        convert.run(img,input,output);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a walkaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405526/3552975), for Java I learned that I can run shell command [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403259/3552975). For jpg, try this:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to jpg /mnt/b.emf
```