# Imagemagick on linux to convert EMF to PNG

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, libreoffice

I am trying to convert an image in EMF format to PNG using Imagemagick on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga), but I am running into the following error:

> convert: no decode delegate for this image format `thumbnail.emf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.
>   convert: no images defined `1.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3068.

How might I fix this?

Comment: Try libreoffice first and then imagemagick as I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405526/3552975).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

> EMF  R  Microsoft Enhanced Metafile (32-bit)  Only available under Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 17):

Install libreoffice and run this command on the folder where your emf files are located:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to png *.emf
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to use inkscape:

```
inkscape -o file.png source.emf
```

See `inkscape --help` for more export options (area to export, dpi, image resolution, background color etc).

Comment: Not imagemagick, but it works. Can also do svg, (e)ps, pdf and LaTeX.

Comment: This worked for me in spite of @ArnaudWeil's comment.

Comment: Maybe MS does put whatever they want into EMF... "** (inkscape:10912): WARNING **: Specified document image5.emf cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)"

Comment: `inkspace -o file.png -d 300 source.emf` (options have changed)

Answer (score 0):

libreoffce will output a png that is a different size than the original image. I used inkscape instead. The arguments have changed (works as of 2024):

```
inkscape -z -f image16.emf -e image16.png
```