# How to read .EMF type image in Python

Tags: python, .emf

I am working on .emf format images. I am unable to open/read them in Python. I know to read other jpeg, png format images.
Can you provide a code for that?

Also, when I open this .emf format image then how to read all images from my folder?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img=Image.open("image/test_image.emf")
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: An EMF file isn't an image, it's instructions for producing an image. So it's much more difficult to process, especially if your OS isn't Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert EMF/WMF files to PNG/JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103891/convert-emf-wmf-files-to-png-jpg)