# clear cache memory using java code

Tags: java

in the linux os, when we send this command:

```
 free -m
```

this result has been appear:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32182      31902        280          0        658      16802
-/+ buffers/cache:      14442      17740
Swap:        65538       7463      58075
```

and when we send a command to clear cache,the cache has been decreased ,i want to do the same but using java,can i do this? 
thank you...

Comment: You can try System.gc(); and System.runFinalization();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run linux commands in java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)

Comment: and how can test if it works?is there a command line for windows 7?

Comment: lol. Of Course there is a command line in Windows, but linux commands will not work on windows. So, if you do a Runtime.exec, you need to implemnt CrossOS behaviour by yourself.

Comment: What "command to clear cache" are you talking about?

Comment: i want to write a program which work on linux and windows.i know that i can use the Runtime class to send a command but i work on only one operating system.so i want to write a java code wich do this.and i want to test this code if it work  on windows so i want to a windows command to test it.

Comment: and what cache are you actually talking about? the one reported by free, is completely unrelated to java. its the amount of memory used by linux for disk caching.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Runtime.exec method.

Basic example:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); // get OS Runtime 
Process pr = run.exec("free -m"); // execute a system command and give back the process
pr.waitFor(); // wait for the process to complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("free -m");
```

But based upon some of the answers here, I am guess that there is confusion as to exactly what you are wanting to achieve.