# Unix commands in java

Tags: java, shell, unix, terminal

I'm trying to execute unix commands in java, like `system("ls");` in C.
I tried this but it doesn't print anithing:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
OutputStream in=p.getOutputStream();
PrintStream print = new PrintStream(in);
print.println("String");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the newer [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, which has more options than the `Runtime.exec` method. The reason why you don't see any output is because the standard output stream of the new process is by default connected to the JVM via a pipe. You can make the new process inherit the JVM's standard output using the `redirectOutput` method:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

You can get a similar result using a shell redirection to the controlling terminal:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "ls > /dev/tty");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: I get the "Redirect cannot be resolved to a variable"
error in Redirect.INHERIT, I have to import something? eclipse doesn't suggest anything

Comment: You can add `import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect` or write `ProcessBuilder.Redirect` instead of just `Redirect`

Comment: I find ProcessBuilder but not ProcessBuilder.Redirect, "cannot be resolved" again :S

Comment: In that case you must be using Java 6 or an earlier version; ProcessBuilder.Redirect was added in Java 7. There are workarounds like using a shell redirection (see my update) or reading the pipe yourself (like in Serdar's answer). Considering that Java 6 has already reached end of public updates and even the end of premier support from Oracle you may want to consider migrating to Java 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

There is nice library for doing this [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec)

```
new ProcessExecutor().command("ls")
      .redirectOutputAsInfo().execute();
```

or

```
String output = new ProcessExecutor().command("ls")
      .readOutput(true).execute()
      .outputUTF8();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read command response (if any) from **Process input stream** as follows:

```
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net time");

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream(); //or p.getErrorStream() on error
        int c;
        StringBuilder commandResponse = new StringBuilder();

        while( (c = is.read()) != -1) {    //read until end of stream
            commandResponse.append((char)c);
        }
        System.out.println(commandResponse);   //Print command response
        is.close();
```

But if an error occurs **Process** writes to **error stream** so you have to check both streams.

Comment: This answer works too, I choose the other for simplicity