# Running a linux service from Java

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to start and stop a linux service from Java. I am using ProcessBuilder as per current accepted practices. I have constructed the following code (webService is a parameter containing the name of the service being started):

```
String[] commands = new String[6]; 

commands[0] = "/bin/sh";
commands[1] = "-c";
commands[2] = "sudo";
commands[3] = "service";
commands[4] = webService;
commands[5] = "start";

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);

Process process = processBuilder.start();

int outcomeOfProcess = process.waitFor();
```

This effectively is calling the command `/bin/sh -c sudo service webService start`. Which when run from the linux terminal of the server runs fine however doesn't work from Java ProcessBuilder (outcomeOfProcess is 1 when this is run).

I have tried `sudo systemctl start webservice.service` as well with no avail - and I also have tried to call a bash script already located on the linux machine but this doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas of how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you set up password-less sudo? Or how do you supply the password?

Comment: try running your java process with sudo, in that way processwill run with higher access and will able to fire admin commands like `sudo`

Comment: Oh, and shouldn't that be `/bin/sh -c "sudo service webService start"`,?

Comment: Consider this library: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/

Comment: Is the java VM running under the same user account as when you try it in the terminal? Or is it part of a web server?

Comment: I deleted my answer because the answer below addresses exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `ProcessBuilder` can handle SO requests. For cases I need to execute host OS commands (Windows/OSX/Linux etc..), I use [`Runtime.exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String command = "/bin/sh -c sudo service " + webService  + " start";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

If you also want to get the output and error exit you can use `Process` and `BufferedReader` as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403259/3850595).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s;
    Process p;

    String command = "/bin/sh -c sudo service " + webService  + " start";

    try {
        // run the command
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        // get the result
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("line: " + s);
        p.waitFor();
        // get the exit code
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

**NOTE:** not a Linux expert, so I can't tell 100% your command line is correct, but yes you can execute it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `sudoers` file which prevented the code executing without a `tty` changing this file slightly meant that it would accept code. Nightmare debugging this as it has taken all day! thanks for all the input!