# Is there any way to start external application and get pid of application and kill them using java or php

Tags: java, php, web, desktop-application

I need to start any application using java and get their pid and then using pid kill them using java code or php code in Linux env

Comment: what your asking has many different answers, you could elaborate more on this. CRON would be an option on linux machines

Comment: for a simple solution in java have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code) at Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). You can run all commands you want and get their output. so start your application. find the pid using ps and kill it.

Comment: you can use `shell_exec('your shell command')`, and it will return the complete output as a string..

Comment: my need is 1  start external application like Firefox.  2  getting pid of firefox . 3 and then kill process using pid .

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how to do exactly that, but you can use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (Java) to do something similar. (You can start and stop the process any time you want with this)

Comment: using ProcessBuilder (Java) start external application but i don't know how to get start process pid and how to stop that .