# converting a shell script to a jar file

Tags: java, linux, jar, javac, executable-jar

I have a following sh file.

```
%~d0
 cd %~dp0
 java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp ../lib/systemRoutines.jar;../lib/userRoutines.jar;.;sqlldr_0_1.jar;../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;../lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar; migration_test.sqlldr_0_1.sqlldr --context=Default --context_param cred_username=cre --context_param cred_password=crepass --context_param cred_env=credev01 %*
```

What I would like to do is to convert this sh file into .jar file. The result jar file will be run by another program. 
How can I do so?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to modify your shell file, then you can use a java code to execute these commands and then build that into a jar.

[How to run linux commands in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)

Please keep in mind to include everything in a single execute() call as the above method executes your linux command in a separate process.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now the problem is that I never wrote a java code so have no idea how to "mix" this code in java format at all :-)

Comment: Are you going to modify the jar file by any chance?

Comment: No I'm not. I just try to change the bash script in a .jar file