# How to execute linux command using Java

Tags: java, linux, command

How do I execute this:

```
ffmpeg -i Missing/Missing.mp4 -vf scale=-1:360 -c:v libx264 -crf 26
    -preset veryslow -c:a copy Missing_new123.m3u8
```

linux command using java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run linux commands in java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "ffmpeg -i Missing/Missing.mp4 -vf scale=-1:360 -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -preset veryslow -c:a copy Missing_new123.m3u8"});
```

see it this helps