# Java Runtime -ERR 'fsctl Command not found

Tags: java, linux, java-runtime-compiler

I run a command using java Runtime.That command work fine when i executed normally on terminal/command promp but unable to execute through Java.Runtime :-

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fs_cli -H x.x.x.x -x 'fsctl loglevel'");
```

It give output "**-ERR 'fsctl Command not found!**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run linux commands in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3403226/608639) and friends.

Comment: No bro,thats not duplicate,i already go through this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolve the error:-

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(builder.command("sh", "-c", "fs_cli -H 10.168.3.135 -x 'fsctl loglevel'").start().getInputStream())).lines().parallel().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```